# Deploy ASP.NET web app on Microsoft Azure using account added as co-admin to subscription

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have created a web app in ASP.NET. I want to deploy this on Microsoft Azure. I have been given an account from my IT company. We need subscription to deploy on Azure, for sure. Then, I have been added as co-admin to subscription by my company, but still I am not able to integrate my account with Visual Studio. Do I need to do any setting? Or, this permission is also not enough ?

Comment: Is there any chance you have multiple "Directories" under that account? You should be able to see them from a dropdown from the top right corner (click on your name). You ONLY see the subscriptions for one directory at a time and it's possible you're viewing a directory that has 0 subscriptions.

Comment: What made this post a down vote?

Comment: @Jaxidian There are 2 directories, but none of them show any subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Co-admin on subscription is definitely enough. You are allowed to do anything in the subscription. Have you tried logging in to https://portal.azure.com with the account?

EDIT: Try opening a new Incognito/InPrivate window with no logins active, and try again with the credentials, making sure they are the ones that are co-admin.

Comment: Yes. I have logged in here. But cannot find any subscription

Comment: See my edit, try again in an Incognito/InPrivate window.

Comment: I tried but cannot find any difference. Is it possible that they have made me co-admin but did not subscribed?

Comment: It's possible it just takes a while. Confirm with them they have added the right account, and wait for a while. If it still doesn't work, you or they should open a support ticket to Azure or contact @AzureSupport on Twitter.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure my thought was logical. Thanks I will ask them. :)